# I'd like to insert any value using 'insert into' but it doesn't work. What is "Column not found error"?

Tags: sql, insert, h2

I created table "member". It has two columns name, id and no values. And I'm trying to insert value "spring" into column name!
But It doesn't work...Can anybody help me please?

I wrote like this:

```
insert into member(name) values("spring");
```

error is:

```
Column "spring" not found; SQL statement:
insert into member(name)
values("spring") [42122-200] 42S22/42122
```

Comment: What is your db?

Comment: I think it is "H2".... I'm sorry for not being detailed..  I'm watching some lecture and my teacher said to download "H2". So I just download h2 db and wrote that command

Comment: Try insert into member(name) values('spring');

Comment: Use single quotes for string constants.  I'm voting to close as a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use single quotes for your String/Varchar values.
Try this query:

```
 insert into member(name) values('spring');
```